# Number of Computers Used in Enterprise?

Tags: statistics

This may not be the right StackExchange, but it seems you're most likely to know where I might find the answer. I'm looking for statistics on the number of computers used in enterprises on an annual basis, similar to the census data kept about home internet users. Does such a table exist, and if so where would I find it?

Answer (score 3):

Why would businesses publish that kind of information? You can't even get an accurate number of systems used at Google or Microsoft; the numbers you find are just rough guesstimates. Not to mention that the numbers would change periodically so it wouldn't be accurate on a week to week basis.

In cases where the "enterprise" is a .com, it could be a competitive secret to them and not something they want to advertise about their infrastructure.

I think the Enterprise itself uses just one "computer" with a few very large processing cores, depending on if you're talking about the A, B, C or Enterprise D, though. The technical guide has some information on that if you look for the one covering the Enterprise D from the Next Generation.

Comment: Was hoping the data would at least be voluntarily reported by some enterprises to give an illustration of the effects of digitization on real GDP. May have to go back to the drawing board on this idea though; thanks for your help!

Comment: Nope, never seen any such information published from big companies. Closest are estimates for companies that are case studies and they won't give specifics (such as Google's farms)